# Set Image MetaDate e.g EXIF Data Using Imagick In PHP

Tags: php, image, exif

I'm trying the set the EXIF data of an image file using Imagick in PHP. Here's the code I'm using:

```
<?php
$image = new Imagick('https://i.imgur.com/N5Inayf.png');
$image->setImageProperty('Exif.Image.Artist', 'Imagick');
echo base64_encode($image);
?>
```

I've used the tags from this ref: https://www.exiv2.org/tags.html

After converting base64_encode to an image file, I'm not getting the values I've set in the code. e.g Author Name, Title, etc.

Comment: What gives echo $image->getImageProperty('Exif.Image.Artist'); ?
Is it related to this : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/imagick.setimageproperty.php#123346 -> " Exif data can be 'modified' but will not be written to the file"

Comment: It gives Imagick. base64 also doesn't contain the EXIF data.